# Can't not get an random item in an array (Angular 10)

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic-framework

I'm trying to randomize items(cards that contain english words) from an flashCards array, so that each card can randomly appear when the user reload the page. I have used Math.floor(Math.random()) function but it doesn't work. How can I get randomly cards from an array of cards?

**home.page.html:**

```
<ion-content padding>
     <app-flash-card *ngFor="let card of flashCards" [ngClass]="randomize()">
        <div class="flash-card-front">{{card.front}}</div>

        <div class="flash-card-back">{{card.back}}</div>
     </app-flash-card>  
</ion-content>
```

**home.page.ts:**

```
export class HomePage {

    flashCards: any;
  
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
        this.flashCards = [
            {back: 'accreditation', front: 'offizielle Zustimmung'},
            {back: 'AIDA', front: 'Attention, Interest, Desire, Action (Aufmerksamkeit, Interresse, Wunsch, Handlung)-> Modell zur Werbewirkung'},
            {back: 'airtime', front: 'Sendezeit'},
            {back: 'ambient noise', front: 'Umgebungsgeräusch'},
            {back: 'ambitious', front: 'ehrgeizig,strebsam'}
        ];
    };
    randomize(){    
        var cards=this.flashCards[Math.floor(Math.random()*this.flashCards.length)];
        return this.flashCards[cards];
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you want to randomize the array before printing their contents ?

Comment: yes, I want to randomize the array

Comment: you might be interested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2450954/how-to-randomize-shuffle-a-javascript-array) , randomize the array on constructor or on OnInit.

Comment: also you are using directive ngClass incorrectly, they are meant for classes, read about them [here](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass)

Comment: shuffle(flashCards) {
  var currentIndex = this.flashCards.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;
 
  // While there remain elements to shuffle...
  while (0 !== currentIndex) {
 
   // Pick a remaining element...
   randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
   currentIndex -= 1;
 
   // And swap it with the current element.
   temporaryValue = flashCards[currentIndex];
   flashCards[currentIndex] = flashCards[randomIndex];
   flashCards[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
  }
  console.log(flashCards);
  return flashCards;
  
 }

Comment: I have replace randomize function with the shuffle function you gave me, but it's gave error :"ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property '4' of undefined". Can you tell me how to fix this error?. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Just to post a complete solution:* As described in the comments, you can simply use the existing shuffle function and access it in the constructor or the ngOnInit function (the Angular way to go). I put your flashCards on a new `var` and set it on `this.flashCards` after shuffling (`this.flashCards` is later used in your html). This will ensure that the array is shuffle before being displayed:

```
import { OnInit } from '@angular/core';

export class HomePage implements OnInit {

    flashCards: any;
  
    constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) { }

    ngOnInit(): void {
        var flashCards = [
            {back: 'accreditation', front: 'offizielle Zustimmung'},
            {back: 'AIDA', front: 'Attention, Interest, Desire, Action (Aufmerksamkeit, Interresse, Wunsch, Handlung)-> Modell zur Werbewirkung'},
            {back: 'airtime', front: 'Sendezeit'},
            {back: 'ambient noise', front: 'Umgebungsgeräusch'},
            {back: 'ambitious', front: 'ehrgeizig,strebsam'}
        ];
        this.flashCards = this.shuffle(flashCards)
    }

    shuffle (array) {
        var currentIndex = array.length, temporaryValue, randomIndex;

        // While there remain elements to shuffle...
        while (0 !== currentIndex) {

            // Pick a remaining element...
            randomIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * currentIndex);
            currentIndex -= 1;

            // And swap it with the current element.
            temporaryValue = array[currentIndex];
            array[currentIndex] = array[randomIndex];
            array[randomIndex] = temporaryValue;
        }

        return array;
    }
}
```

Additionally, remove your `[ngClass]` and just write it like this:

```
<ion-content padding>
     <app-flash-card *ngFor="let card of flashCards">
        <div class="flash-card-front">{{card.front}}</div>

        <div class="flash-card-back">{{card.back}}</div>
     </app-flash-card>  
</ion-content>
```

The shuffling is done in `ngOnInit` and `[ngClass]` would anyway not the correct way to do so.

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explaination!!!! It helps me a lot!